# Ordering of rows with different kinds of objects

Tags: order-by

I have a table of real estate objects. The objects are shown in three lists (sell, rent long, rent short), each object in exactly one list (defined by an ENUM field).

I want to add field `seq` INT to the table to be able to reorder objects in every of the three lists (`ORDER BY seq`). Should I permit objects of different lists have the same seq?

Comment: Would you ever be selecting more than one object type at the same time?

Comment: @Hogan: Never (except of the routine which re-generates all output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will never be selecting more than one object type at the same time you can have duplicates over types.

Whenever I've done it this way I've always regretted it.  It does not cost much to make then unique and it can solve lots of issues.  (For example a rent long changes to a rent short).

If it is not "to hard" I highly recommend not sharing values in this case.